# Adding Elevation Data to a Satellite Image Raster File from DEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, dem

I have a satellite image raster file of an area and a DEM of the same area. I can Extract Values to Points by using this DEM as it contains the 'z' value i.e the elevation information in meter.  The image raster file is a color image which is georeferenced and has no 'z' values. I'm trying to add the 'z' value of the DEM to this image raster file using ArcGIS 10. I have tried this process:
Adding the 3 Bands of the image Band 1, Band 2, Band 3 along with the DEM file to Composite Bands tools and to create a new composite raster. But I failed to find whether the 'z' value of the DEM is added to the newly created image raster after Composite Bands tools operation.
My objective is to make this image raster file associated with the elevation value of the DEM.
Is there any error in this process?

Comment: As a relatively new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: what is the purpose of doing that? Is it for display or for analysis?

Comment: Actually the initial target was to use the raster image for mapping purpose. Showing the elevation difference like in a DEM when Hillsahade effect is used from symbology. I've done it using the ArcScene to give it a 3D effect instead of ArcMap. As the image file has no Z value associated with it. I'm trying to extract the values from the DEM and trying to integrate it with it to the image Raster file. I've tried Composite Raster but it didn't help. Is there any other possible method?

Comment: To be more specific, as the DEM has elevation value so I can classify the DEM as per the elevation value then when Hillshade effect is applied it looks somewhat 3D. But as the image file has only RGB composite information and x, y values, I can't classify them as per the elevation. I'm trying to add the elevation value which I will get from the DEM so that the image file will be a raster file with elevation information.

Comment: composite band should work. make sure that you add each individual band and not the full JP2000 image.